# Is there any functionality similar to Criteria API in MyBatis, or any wrapper like QueryDSL to provide that functionality over it?

Tags: ibatis, criteria-api, mybatis, querydsl

In `JPA/Hibernate`, we can write type-safe queries and accumulate our query predicates one step at a time. I believe that there is no equivalent of that in `MyBatis`, but is there any abstraction framework (like `QueryDSL`) that provides a layer above `MyBatis`, that can enable us to write criteria-like queries. My basic reason for wanting the criteria API is that I need to construct a query, each of whose predicates come from a separate logic.

Comment: Does MyBatis provide a declarative domain model that could be used for such an abstraction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MBG ([MyBatis Generator](http://www.mybatis.org/generator/)) with [example classes](http://www.mybatis.org/generator/generatedobjects/exampleClassUsage.html).

Though I doubt that the example classes are as powerful as Hibernate's Criteria Queries, they should suit well your task of constructing queries.

Answer (score 2):

MyBatis Generator seems pretty unmaintained to me. Also need to generate classes from existing DB during build is quiet cumbersome.

Isn't MyBatis [SQL Builder Class](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/statement-builders.html) a better solution?